# Button inside updatepanel not working

Tags: .net, asp.net, gridview, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I am retrieving download urls from a database on `Button2` but when I put my `GridView` inside the `UpdatePanel`, it gives me following error:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException:

Code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" 
                  EmptyDataText="No Uploads are found" ShowEmptyTable="True"
                  ShowFooterWhenEmpty="False" Style="margin-top: 20px" 
                  OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged"
                  OnRowDataBound="GridView2_RowDataBound">
      <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False" HeaderText="Receive">
        <ItemTemplate> 
          <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="select" Text="Receive" /> 
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
    </asp:GridView>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Does it give that error on compiling, or on clicking the button? Is there any more information with the error?

Comment: Hey wait - this seems to be a direct copy of your previous question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736912/button-in-gridview-not-working-when-gridview-is-inside-updatepanel - can you edit that, or give it some TLC, rather than pointlessly repeating it?

Comment: @Ralph 
it ws jst by mistake not intentionally!!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a trigger within your UpdatePanel:

```
</ContentTemplate> 
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button2" EventName="Click" />        
</Triggers>
```

Comment: Well, presumably the UpdatePanel end tag is after the end of the GridView, so the GridView should treat all children controls as triggers, so I doubt if that would be necessary.

Comment: Well! yeah it works...ijust used nested updatepanel for button and trigger it inside it..it wrks...whats with this child as trigger thing..it doesnt seem to apply much what it says!!!

Comment: may be these table controls are not so compatible with updapanels even when converted to templates!!